# Is it possible to allocate more memory for the debugging process?

Tags: c++, memory

I need to process an entire chapter of a book but my program freezes and stops at some point. I don't know what the exact problem is, but I think it's due to the size of the heap being too small.

Comment: It could be. You'd better post your code to find the problem.

Comment: Use the debugger to find out where?

Comment: i could free up some space by deleting object vectors but i don't want to do that before i really have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default it's 1 MB in Visual Studio, if that's what you're using.

Right click your project and go to **Properties**. On the left side, click on **Linker**, then click on **System**.  You'll see **Heap Commit Size** in there -- just modify that.

You can do the same thing to the Stack.

If you want to set it programmatically, looking into this [HeapCommitSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712541%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [StackCommitSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vclinkertool.stackcommitsize%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

As an aside, you should set aside some time and read these: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh851882(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: so if i have a vector i will be able to store a lot more?

Comment: @OnTheFly That's the idea.

Comment: @Noobacode - It may start off as 1mb. The program can go to the OS and ask for more or say you can have this back.

Comment: @EdHeal Hmm, well, I don't think he's reaching his 4GB limit from one book chapter.  There could be a different underlying problem.  I wish he'd post his code.

Comment: what about qt creator?

Comment: @OnTheFly Code-wise, the same.  As far as in the settings... I think it's somewhere under Tools -> Options.  I haven't used it in a while, so I'm not sure.

Comment: I can increase stack depth under debugger and string length but not the heap size

Comment: @OnTheFly Well, according to Qt folks, by default, qmake increases heap size to 8.3MB.  That is actually a hard limit for the application that qmake assigns and the application can't increase it.  But as far within qmake itself, when you're creating an application, it can increase the limit up to 33MB.  It doesn't look like you can set your own limit from qt as they want that level of protection against nasty applications.

Comment: @OnTheFly So, I recommend taking the programmatic route.